# How to explain mongodb query plan with PHP MongoDB driver

Tags: php, mongodb

The current PHP MongoDB client doesn't include an `explain()` feature in the query builder. How the explain information could be retrieved for the query below?

```php
use MongoDB\Client;
$client = new Client($mongoUri);
$database = $client->selectDatabase('someDB');
$collection = $database->selectCollection('collectionName');
$results = $collection->find(['key' => 'value'], ['sort' => ['key2' => -1]]);
```

MongoDB client: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb.php

`MongoDB::command` could be a way to the solution. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.command.php

Note! There is a deprecated mongodb client that has this feature.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it:

1. Get the find command that the driver sends to the database for your query. It would look like [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/find/). Generally these can be obtained from command monitoring, hopefully [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-monitoring-commandstartedevent.php) works.
2. Send an [explain command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/explain/) giving the find command as the argument using the driver-provided facility to send arbitrary commands to the database. Or, use `mongo` shell for this part.